# check if key exists in array that matches string

Tags: php

I receive a feed from a 3rd party, which includes a location string for each object.

I loop through each object, checking the location and storing a latitude/longitude value for it based on matching the location to a locations DB I have.

Sometimes, the location string isn't well formatted/ there are too many variations/ the locations DB just doesn't match anything.

I have setup an array in a config file of 'special locations' that I want to be able to match against should the location match fail.

e.g, in my array I will have:

```
Aberdeen => ( 
     latitude => LATVAL,
     longitude => LONGVAL
),
Greater London => (
     latitude => LATVAL,
     longitude => LONGVAL
)
```

and I may get an object from the feed with a location string of

```
'Aberdeen (EU Travel)'
```

and another may be:

```
'Aberdeen Airport, Grampia'
```

In these cases, I would want to match Aberdeen, and be able to get the associated lat/lon.

How can I check my array, to see if any keys are within the location string? or the location string contains a key from the array

Comment: http://php.net/array_keys, http://php.net/preg_grep

Comment: these links helped me solve my query, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if we approached it like this?

```
// Function to compare and find and return;
function checkIfContains($find,$locations)
{
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($locations as $loc => $value)
    {
        if (strpos($loc,$find) !== false) {
            $newArray[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}

// Sample data
$locations = array(
    'Aberdeen' => array(
        'latitude' => '123.123123213',
        'longitude' => '5.34234324'
    ),
    'Aberdeen (EU Travel)' => array(
        'latitude' => '112.4344443',
        'longitude' => '1.23444322'
    ),
    'Aberdeen Airport, Grampia' => array(
        'latitude' => '6.434443',
        'longitude' => '23.34445'
    ),
    'Greater London' => array(
        'latitude' => '13.545453',
        'longitude' => '11.233467'
    )
);

// Filtered array with only the Aberdeen Elements
$filteredArray = checkIfContains('Aberdeen' , $locations);

// Debugging Test
foreach($filteredArray as $loc)
{
  echo $loc['latitude'] .',', $loc['longitude'].'<br>';
}
```

This allow us to find results by a partial string match.

let me know if this something like this works.